# Prove that every sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ is abelian.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H \unlhd  G$ where $|H|$ is odd and $G/H$ is abelian.

Let $P$ be a sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$, then can we say that $P$ is abelian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** It is sufficient to prove that the restriction of the quotient map $P \to G/H$ is injective. Indeed, if that's true, $P$ would be isomorphic to a subgroup of an abelian group, and would thus be abelian.